# XSS as attack vector even if XSS data not stored?

Tags: security, xss

I have a question about XSS

Can forms be used as a vector for XSS even if the data is not stored in the database and used at a later point?

i.e. in php the code would be this:

```
<form input="text" value="<?= @$_POST['my_field'] ?>" name='my_field'>
```

Showing an alert box (demonstrate that JS can be run) on your own browser is trivial with the code above. But is this exploitable across browsers as well?
The only scenario I see is where you trick someone into visiting a certain page, i.e. a combination of CSRF and XSS.

"Stored in a database and used at a later point": the scenario I understand about CSS is where you're able to post data to a site that runs JavaScript and is shown on a page in a browser that has greater/different privileges than your own.
But, to be clear, this is *not* wat I'm talking about above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's still an attack vector.

What you need to consider is:

*Can an authenticated user be tricked into viewing this page with maliciously-crafted data?*

The answer is this case is yes (assuming you have authenticated users). Because it's possible to direct someone to your site and pass in malicious variables to that field.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's still an attack vector, although impact is more situational.

Here's a contrived scenario that expands on previous answers if the form requires authentication to reach (and is easier if the site doesn't care if forms are submitted via POST or GET):

1) Attacker uses CSRF to login the victim using the attacker's credentials (e.g. <iframe src=http://../login?id=...&pass=..."></iframe>). This way the attacker brings the form to the victim and it doesn't matter if the victim doesn't have an account.
2) Attacker uses another CSRF to execute XSS against the form, which asks the victim for some credentials, etc. (This is where some convincing social engineering needs to occurr or the attacker has some useful JavaScript to use within the browser's Same Origin for the site.)

Another contrived scenario in which the vulnerable form performs some important action, like transfer money between accounts:

0) Vulnerable form uses hidden form fields with random values to prevent CSRF. The attacker doesn't know what the values are and can't set up a proper attack.
1) Attacker creates a CSRF payload that includes JavaScript to read a form's random csrf tokens (i.e. pull them from the browser's DOM).
2) Victim logs into site.
3) Attacker lures victim to CSRF payload, CSRF bootstraps the form request with the correct csrf tokens because it's executing in the victim's browser, within the victim site's Same Origin, and using the victim's auth session. The attacker doesn't need to know the csrf tokens, just be able to manipulate the form fields that store them.
4) Attacker benefits from having the victim submit the form -- no pop-ups or social engineering necessary aside from luring the victim to the CSRF payload, but the form needs to do something "useful" for the attacker.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you are mean is, since User 2 cannot be showing previous data added by User 1, so can the XSS happen?  So if User 1 hack the URL so that some $_GET params got displayed on the webpage as well (and then even, change it to a tinyurl), and spread this URL saying that it is really worthwhile to see this page, etc, then it might be possible.

So it is still better to escape all params when displaying the page.

Answer (score 0):

That is absolutely a valid form of XSS. XSS comes in two forms - stored and reflected. Reflected is much more common, but stored has the potential to be more damaging. Reflected XSS is usually used as part of a social engineering attack. An attacker creates a URL like the following:
http://host.com/page.php?my_field=malicious_code
They will often shorten the URL with tinyutl or bit.ly, and get it out with the usual social engineering methods (email, message board, twitter, hijacked facebook accounts, etc.)